# Passing pointers between C and Java through JNI

Tags: java, pointers, java-native-interface, cuda

At the moment, i'm trying to create a Java-application which uses CUDA-functionality. The connection between CUDA and Java works fine, but i've got another problem and wanted to ask, if my thoughts about it are correct.

When i call a native function from Java, i pass some data to it, the functions calculates something and returns a result. Is it possible, to let the first function return a reference (pointer) to this result which i can pass to JNI and call another function that does further calculations with the result?

My idea was to reduce the overhead that comes from copying data to and from the GPU by leaving the data in the GPU memory and just passing a reference to it so other functions can use it.

After trying some time, i thought for myself, this shouldn't be possible, because pointers get deleted after the application ends (in this case, when the C-function terminates). Is this correct? Or am i just to bad in C to see the solution?

Edit: 
Well, to expand the question a little bit (or make it more clearly): Is memory allocated by JNI native functions deallocated when the function ends? Or may i still access it until either the JNI application ends or when i free it manually?

Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802340/632951

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I used the following approach:

in your JNI code, create a struct that would hold references to objects you need. When you first create this struct, return its pointer to java as a `long`. Then, from java you just call any method with this `long` as a parameter, and in C cast it to a pointer to your struct.

The structure will be in the heap, so it will not be cleared between different JNI calls.

EDIT: I don't think you can use  long ptr = `(long)&address;` since address is a static variable. Use it the way Gunslinger47 suggested, i.e. create new instance of class or a struct (using new or malloc) and pass its pointer.

Comment: That's how i did it now - i send the pointer back to java as a long and pass it to C. But how do i tell C that the long it just received is an address?

long *ptr = (long*)&address;

That's what i tried, but i don't get the value which should be at the address, i only get the address itself (or some other addresses but no value :( )

Comment: `MyClass *pObject = ...; long lp = (long)pObject; pObject = (*pObject)lp;`

Comment: Use long on both x32 and x64 platforms? I'm glad we won't be moving to 128-bit machines any time soon...

Comment: Hello @Denis Tulskiy , i have a question regarding converting a long pointer in java to an array i use itk in the same concept and i got a pointer to the image data but i dont know how to get the array from the pointer. i tried to use com.sun.jna.Pointer but i didnt know gow to make it points to the same data the passed pointer refer to.

Comment: I share @dhardy's concern. This solution is not portable - there is no guarantee that `long` will be large enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: Denis can you please write an pseudo/sample code to understand this. Also what about class object instead struct, is this feasible! I am following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32840427/2624806). Please suggest.

Comment: `sun.misc.unsafe` makes hefty use of longs as pointers, so it's *effectively* supported, regardless whether Oracle actually approves of it... so, accept the contract at your own risk.

Comment: I also share @dhardy's concern. One way would be to pass a java byte array where every byte in the array is 8 bits of the pointer value (and make the array different length depending on the system). However, this means that you would also have to pass the size of the pointer to the JNI function.

Comment: @AlexanderNajafi: in that case I think it's better to have a known-sized key for your data. Keep a hash-map from key to pointer and return the key from native code to java.

Answer (score 21):

In C++ you can use any mechanism you want to allocate/free memory: the stack, malloc/free, new/delete or any other custom implementation. The only requirement is that if you allocated a block of memory with one mechanism, you have to free it with the same mechanism, so you can't call `free` on a stack variable and you can't call `delete` on `malloc`ed memory.

JNI has its own mechanisms for allocating/freeing JVM memory:

- NewObject/DeleteLocalRef
- NewGlobalRef/DeleteGlobalRef
- NewWeakGlobalRef/DeleteWeakGlobalRef

These follow the same rule, the only catch is that local refs can be deleted "en masse" either explicitly, with `PopLocalFrame`, or implicitly, when the native method exits.

JNI doesn't know how you allocated your memory, so it can't free it when your function exits. Stack variables will obviously be destroyed because you're still writing C++, but your GPU memory will remain valid.

The only problem then is how to access the memory on subsequent invocations, and then you can use Gunslinger47's suggestion:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_MyJavaClass_Function1() {
    MyClass* pObject = new MyClass(...);
    return (long)pObject;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJavaClass_Function2(jlong lp) {
    MyClass* pObject = (MyClass*)lp;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 16):

While the accepted answer from @denis-tulskiy does make sense, I've personnally followed suggestions from [here](https://rkennke.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/efficient-jni-programming-iv-wrapping-native-data-objects/).

So instead of using a pseudo-pointer type such as `jlong` (or `jint` if you want to save some space on 32bits arch), use instead a `ByteBuffer`. For example:

```
MyNativeStruct* data; // Initialized elsewhere.
jobject bb = (*env)->NewDirectByteBuffer(env, (void*) data, sizeof(MyNativeStruct));
```

which you can later re-use with:

```
jobject bb; // Initialized elsewhere.
MyNativeStruct* data = (MyNativeStruct*) (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, bb);
```

For very simple cases, this solution is very easy to use. Suppose you have:

```
struct {
  int exampleInt;
  short exampleShort;
} MyNativeStruct;
```

On the Java side, you simply need to do:

```
public int getExampleInt() {
  return bb.getInt(0);
}

public short getExampleShort() {
  return bb.getShort(4);
}
```

Which saves you from writing *lots* of boilerplate code ! One should however pay attention to byte ordering as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29749706/136285).

Answer (score 11):

Java wouldn't know what to do with a pointer, but it should be able to store a pointer from a native function's return value then hand it off to another native function for it to deal with.  C pointers are nothing more than numeric values at the core.

Another contibutor would have to tell you whether or not the pointed to graphics memory would be cleared between JNI invocations and if there would be any work-arounds.

Comment: About your second paragraph: The only thing to look out for is to make sure that any memory allocated gets deallocated as well. The recommended approach is to have some kind of close/dispose() method on the object holding the reference. finalizers are tempting but they come with a couple of drawbacks making it worth avoiding them if possible.

Comment: I shouldn't have written "the only thing" btw... JNI is full of pits to fall into.

Comment: I already included functions to free allocated memory, so that should no problem :) The main problem still is: Does memory stay allocated if i do net free it? I mean, including addresses and values...i know that i will get memory leaks an so on if i don't do it, so i already included that ;-)

Comment: @Volker: It depends on how you allocate it. The only exception to the rule that you have to deallocate/free the memory yourself is normally if something is allocated on the stack. If it is, it will be "freed" when the stack pointer is moved back at exit of a function. So if you have allocated memory using some kind of memory allocation function (except for "alloca") you will have to free it. It is really not at all related to java. As soon as you have made the JNI jump the rules are from the C world unless you use java objects.

Comment: Fredrik, your answer is correct, and really ought to be moved into its own answer for credit.

Comment: "C pointers are nothing more than `long` values at the core." - There is nothing in the C standard that says this, and this is invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question was already officially answered, but I'd like to add my solution:
Instead of trying to pass a pointer, put the pointer in a Java array (at index 0) and pass that to JNI. JNI code can get and set the array element using `GetIntArrayRegion`/`SetIntArrayRegion`.

In my code, I need the native layer to manage a file descriptor (an open socket). The Java class holds a `int[1]` array and passes it to the native function. The native function can do whatever with it (get/set) and put back the result in the array.

Answer (score 7):

If you are allocating memory dynamically (on the heap) inside of the native function, it is not deleted.  In other words, you are able to retain state between different calls into native functions, using pointers, static vars, etc.

Think of it a different way: what could you do safely keep in an function call, called from another C++ program?  The same things apply here.  When a function is exited, anything on the stack for that function call is destroyed; but anything on the heap is retained unless you explicitly delete it.

Short answer: as long as you don't deallocate the result you're returning to the calling function, it will remain valid for re-entrance later.  Just make sure to clean it up when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Its best to do this exactly how Unsafe.allocateMemory does.

Create your object then type it to (uintptr_t) which is a 32/64 bit unsigned integer.

```
return (uintptr_t) malloc(50);

void * f = (uintptr_t) jlong;
```

This is the only correct way to do it.

Here is the sanity checking Unsafe.allocateMemory does.

```
inline jlong addr_to_java(void* p) {
  assert(p == (void*)(uintptr_t)p, "must not be odd high bits");
  return (uintptr_t)p;
}

UNSAFE_ENTRY(jlong, Unsafe_AllocateMemory(JNIEnv *env, jobject unsafe, jlong size))
  UnsafeWrapper("Unsafe_AllocateMemory");
  size_t sz = (size_t)size;
  if (sz != (julong)size || size < 0) {
    THROW_0(vmSymbols::java_lang_IllegalArgumentException());
  }
  if (sz == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  sz = round_to(sz, HeapWordSize);
  void* x = os::malloc(sz, mtInternal);
  if (x == NULL) {
    THROW_0(vmSymbols::java_lang_OutOfMemoryError());
  }
  //Copy::fill_to_words((HeapWord*)x, sz / HeapWordSize);
  return addr_to_java(x);
UNSAFE_END
```

Comment: This is **not** the standard's definition of `uintptr_t`. It is a **very** bad idea to do that. It is defined as being large enough to hold any pointer, and can be **any** length this requires. Typically on a 64-bit system this would be 64-bits, but the standard does not even permit that assumption. You should never make assumptions about the size of `uintptr_t`.

Comment: This is how the JVM allocates memory on 32 and 64 bit systems.  Assignment of uintptr_t allows for a clean conversion to a jlong.  I'm not going to debate if it is a good way or not but it is the way that the JVM does it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, using a global `static` variable in the java-c C glue file, passing the variable by reference to C, and returning the variable that have been changed from C to Java. Will need two Java function calls though.

Here is an example using Android development in Kotlin:

First, C code (a simple function that increments a variable passed by reference):

```
// lib.c
void cfunction(int *number)
{
    *number += 1;
}
```

Then we usually have another C code used like a glue, to manage Java <strike>idiocies</strike> features

```
// glue.c
static int number;

void cfunction(int *);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_someapp_MainActivity_inc(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint value)
{
    number = value;
    cfunction(&number);
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_someapp_MainActivity_getnumber(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
    return number;
}
```

It uses a global variable `number` (accessible only inside the file glue.c thanks to the `static` keyword) and can be accessed externally using the getter function `getnumber`. So basically we needed an additional function and a static global variable to call a C lib that expects a pointer and changes its reference.

A `CMakeLists.txt` would looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

project("someapp")

add_library(somelib SHARED
            glue.c
            lib.c)
```

Finally the Android (Kotlin) part:

```
package com.example.someapp

// imports

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // How to use a C call by ref in Kotlin
        inc(4)
        val number = getnumber()
        Toast.makeText(this, number.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    external fun inc(number: Int)

    external fun getnumber(): Int

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("somelib")
        }
    }
}
```

It should display `5`.