# Passing a pointer from JNI to Java using a long

Tags: java, c, pointers, struct, java-native-interface

I'm trying to pass a structure as a pointer from JNI to Java to be able to pass it back later from Java to JNI. I have read this thread: [Passing pointers between C and Java through JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632367/passing-pointers-between-c-and-java-through-jni), but I did not succeed.

I have a pretty complex structure : `struct myStruct_s myStruct;`

From Java, I call a JNI function to initialize the structure and to return a long (pointer to the structure):

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_example_ExampleJNI_getStruct(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls) {
    struct myStruct_s mystruct;
    long *lp = (long*)&myStruct;
    return lp;
}
```

Then I call a Java method with that long in argument. In JNI I want to be able to use the strcuture created earlier. I do like this:

```
JNIEEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_example_ExampleJNI_methode1(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg) {
    struct myStruct_s *arg = (struct myStruct_s *)&jarg;
    ...
}
```

Well it doesn't work. I guess my cast of the long into the struct is wrong. How should I do it?
Thank you.

---

**EDIT** : Thanks for the hints, here are the working functions

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_example_ExampleJNI_methode1(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg) {
    struct myStruct_s *arg;
    arg = (struct myStruct_s *)jarg;
    ...
} 

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_example_ExampleJNI_getStruct(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls) {
    struct myStruct_s *myStruct;
    myStruct = (struct myStruct_s *)malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct_s));
    long lp = (long)myStruct;
    return lp;
}
```

Comment: Beware that `jlong`is not necessarily equal to `long` depending on the target platform. If you are running this on a platform where it is in fact a `long long`, this will fail, so you should always cast to `jlong`explicitly.

Comment: leochab but how you will get access of strct object at Java layer. How to access local variable defined inside struct. Also is this possible to do same with some c++ class object. I''m following similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32840427/2624806).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example

```
struct myStruct_s mystruct;
```

is a local variable on the stack, and therefore not available after the function returns. Possubly that's just a cut-down of your code, but if not then use a malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct_s)) to get yourself a heap allocation.

That then raises the question of when you are going to free that allocation, watch out for memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

The memory of this structure is destroyed after the method is returned because it was put into the stack, not into the heap, try it:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_example_ExampleJNI_getStruct(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls) {
    long *lp = (long*)malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct_s));
    return lp;
}
```

Ps: why *long** and not simple *long*?

Answer (score 1):

In additiona to @Moise's suggestion I would cast the pointer to a `long` ratehr than a `long *`

```
long lp = (long)&myStruct;
```