# Passing pointers between C and Java through JNI

Tags: java, c, pointers, casting, java-native-interface

I've been storing c pointers in Java through JNI by following the advice of @tulskiy in this post [Passing pointers between C and Java through JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632367/passing-pointers-between-c-and-java-through-jni/1634310#1634310)

The trick is to cast the pointer as a jlong. So from c I have `return (jlong) ptr;`

I'm returning a jlong (always 64 bits) because I want my code to work on both 64 and 32 bit systems. The size in memory of a 64 bit pointer on a 64 bit computer is 64 and it follows that on a 32-bit computer, the size of the pointer in memory is 32 bits.

The problem is that on the 32 bit machine I get a compiler warning saying "casting to integer from pointer of different size." The warnings goes away if I have 
`return (jlong) (int32_t) ptr;` However this code is not good for the 64 bit machine.

I would like to have my code compile without warnings so that if there is a legitimate warning I will see it. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are various handy integer types in C. The one you want is probably intptr_t or uintptr_t:

```
return (jlong)(intptr_t) ptr;
```

The difference?

- Casting from `intptr_t` to `jlong` and back is guaranteed to work provided `jlong` is big enough (which you're implicitly assuming it is anyway).
- Casting from `uinttptr_t` to `jlong` and back avoids a sign-extension, but is undefined behaviour if the `uintptr_t` is too big to fit in a `jlong` (but all "sane" architectures/compilers just use two's complement arithmetic)

Answer (score 1):

Try casting with intptr_t (store a pointer regardless of the platform capacity).