# Cast a function pointer to a long

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am not sure if that is feasible, but I need to cast a function pointer to long in order to map C level code back to java code.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I have seen long to function pointer not the other way around ?

Comment: Undefined behavior: _A pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type (6.3.2.3)_

Comment: Do you refer to section 6.3 in C99 standard ?

Comment: For the code I cannot, but may be I will do a small example, I look for a way to pass function pointer to Java code with JNI

Comment: In the Annex: _J.2 Undefined behavior_

Comment: Doing some minimal testing, casting to `long` does not seem to change the pointer bitwise. So I'd say it is safe to pass back as a `jlong`.

Comment: Please be more specific, cast in which language, and how exactly, show the code?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the idea here is that, since Java does not have pointers, you need to cast C pointers to `jlong` (which is just a `long`) to be able to pass it back to Java code. There you can store it, or pass it back to another native function, in which you would cast it back to the right function type to then call it.

Comment: @AlterMann You aren't quoting the standard correctly. First of all, Annex J is merely an informative summary, it is not normative, so quoting something from there proves nothing. The actual normative text in 6.3.2.3/6 is this: "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
type." So it is not necessarily undefined behavior.

Comment: @JornVernee Yes that is right

Comment: @Lundin Yep, converting function pointers to integers, and vice-versa, is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer's value is an integer, you just need to know what exactly you are doing, and allocate enough storage to store the pointer's value. (In a 32bit OS, a pointer occupies 32bit storage, in a 64bit OS, pointer occupies 64bit storage).

A C example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun()
{
    printf("fun\n");
    return;
}

typedef void (*fun_type)();

int main()
{
    long long int a = (long long int)fun;

    fun_type func_point = (fun_type)a;

    func_point();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Casting `long long int` to a pointer and vice versa will issue a warning on certain 32-bit compilers. The correct way is to cast them through [`intptr_t`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6543455/3448419).