# Using GetDirectBufferAddress from JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to understand how to use `GetDirectBufferAddress` from the JNI layer. To understand I've build a very simple example:

```java
public class my_image_info {
  static {
      System.loadLibrary("my_jni");
  }
  private java.nio.ByteBuffer image_info_bb;
  native static void initc( java.nio.ByteBuffer bb );
  my_image_info()
    {
    image_info_bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 5 * 4 );
    initc( image_info_bb );
    }
  public java.nio.ByteBuffer getBB() {
    return image_info_bb;
  }
  static public void main(String argv[]) {
    my_image_info fii = new my_image_info();
    java.nio.ByteBuffer bb = fii.getBB();
    System.out.println("1: " + bb.getInt(0));
    System.out.println("2: " + bb.getInt(4));
    System.out.println("3: " + bb.getInt(8));
    System.out.println("4: " + bb.getInt(12));
    System.out.println("5: " + bb.getInt(16));
}
```

And then from the native JNI layer:

```c
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_1image_1info_initc
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject jobj)
{
  int *iBuf = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, jobj);
  iBuf[0] = -2;
  iBuf[1] = -1;
  iBuf[2] = 0;
  iBuf[3] = 1;
  iBuf[4] = 2;
}
```

If I run this example over here (debian/linux wheezy amd64) with openjdk :

```text
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (6b34-1.13.6-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Here is what I see:

```text
1: -16777217
2: -1
3: 0
4: 16777216
5: 33554432
```

I understand the values for index 2 & 3. But all other values do not make any sense to me, I would have expected something like:

```text
1: -2
2: -1
3: 0
4: 1
5: 2
```

What did I misunderstood from the `ByteBuffer` usage in JNI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I missed from the documentation is that by default `java.nio.ByteBuffer` is actually using `BIG_ENDIAN` byte order. Which explains the behavior I was seeing on my `LITTLE_ENDIAN` system. See ref [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#BIG_ENDIAN).

My code now reads as:

```java
image_info_bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 5 * 4 );
image_info_bb.order( java.nio.ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN );
```

It appears that by default it is always `BIG_ENDIAN`, and no effort has been made so far to provide an API for `LITTLE_ENDIAN`, as explained in the bug report [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5043362) (JDK-5043362 : (bf) NewDirectByteBuffer always has order ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).

---

Documentation has been updated recently to reflect that:

- [JDK-8225152 : Release Note: JNI NewDirectByteBuffer Creates Direct Buffer That Is java.nio.ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8225152)