# Read values from DirectByteBuffer in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI development. I am trying to simply just iterate or read value from direct byte buffer (LongBuffer) with JNI.

I first create a DirectByteBuffer as follows:

```
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(5 * 8);

    buf.putLong(12);
    buf.putLong(4);
    buf.putLong(9);
    buf.putLong(7);
    buf.putLong(8);

    buf.rewind();

    LongBuffer lBuf = buf.asLongBuffer();

    // native method
    long ret = this.quickSelect0(lBuf, 0, lBuf.remaining(), 2);
```

Native Code:

```
    // using long* b/c we are using a LongBuffer
    long* addr = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, longBuffer);
    printf ("\n1st element = %lu", addr[0]);
    printf ("\n2nd element = %lu", addr[1]);
```

The output is some address instead of the values in the buffer:

```
    1st element = 864691128455135232 
    2nd element = 288230376151711744
```

What am i missing?

Comment: I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745584/using-getdirectbufferaddress-from-jni