# Why does write() not accept a pointer from a JNI ByteBuffer?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

I'm writing a JNI function that takes a ByteBuffer as parameter and writes some of its content to a (special) file under Linux. The code looks like this:

```c
/*
 * Class:     myPackage_myClass
 * Method:    writeByteBuffer
 * Signature: (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_myPackage_myClass_writeByteBuffer
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject jBuffer, jint jLen)
{
  /* getting my file descriptor (fd) */
  const void* pointer = (void *) (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,(jobject)jBuffer);
  fprintf(stderr,"Address %p\n",pointer); //gives for example : "Address 0x7f58ac680640"
  int res = (int) write(fd, pointer,jLen);
  if(res < jLen) {
    throwErrnoExceptionError(env);
    return cleanup_running(ERR_NR);
  }
  return OK;
}
```

If I try to run it, it gives me an "invalid argument" error (errno 22).

However, the following code runs without problems:

```c
/*
 * Class:     myPackage_myClass
 * Method:    writeByteBuffer
 * Signature: (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_myPackage_myClass_writeByteBuffer
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject jBuffer, jint jLen)
{
/* getting my file descriptor (fd) */
  char test[] = "Just some random text to test";
  int res = (int) write(fd, test,jLen);
  if(res < jLen) {
    throwErrnoExceptionError(env);
    return cleanup_running(ERR_NR);
  }
  return OK;
}
```

I checked, the buffer address is not `NULL` (I checked with a java debugger: The pointer corresponds to the `address` member of my `ByteBuffer` instance) and the buffers capacity is way bigger then jLen

Why does the call to write() does not work with my buffer, when it works using a directly allocated string?

Comment: You've left out the important part, replacing it by `/* error handling */`. Please don't post fake code.

Comment: The `errno` is [probably] coming from the `write` syscall. It doesn't like the address that has been passed. Try: `void *adr = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,(jobject)jBuffer); printf("%p\n",adr); write(fd,adr,jLen);` I bet `adr` will be "funny". See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745584/using-getdirectbufferaddress-from-jni implies that you get back "big endian" instead of "little endian"

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I don't have full rights to post all code that I want, that is why I redacted it a bit. Please tell me, if you still miss something relevant and why.

Comment: @CraigEstey Given the fact that I am on  byte level, how can endianess matter here?

Comment: It explains that in the link. So, when you did the `printf` as I suggested, what did you get?

Comment: @CraigEstey Nothing in that link implies that the address itself is big-endian. But he should certainly error-check his `GetDirectBufferAddress()` call. Could be zero for example, if it isn't really a direct byte buffer. Why he is casting a `jobject` to `jobject` is another mystery.

Comment: @user207421 Ah, I misread malat's answer in the link to imply the address was coming back big endian vs. the buffer contents. As to [this] OP's issue, it could be _any_ arg to `write`. But, since OP's [simplified] working version uses [only] a different pointer, that tends to point to the buffer address [vs. fd or len]. Either it's out-of-range [or NULL].

Comment: @CraigEstey I updated my code, so you can see the Address. I ran it using a java debugger and found out that it is the same address as the base address of my ByteBuffer (in decimal notation)