# Where do I save my "this" when communicating between C++ and JAVA using JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a class in c++ called `kitten`

```
class kitten
{
public:
 void ChangeColor(int newColor);
 int GetColor();
}
```

Now using JNI I want to give my java program the ability to use this class.

I know how to use JNI to give my java program the ability to call C style functions, but this is a member function.

I thought about something like add a C style function called 
`kitten* CreateNewKitten();`, which will have one line : `return new kitten();`

And then somehow return this native `kitten` object to JAVA and then the JAVA code will call C style function :

```
ChangeColor(kitten* myKitten, int newColor)
{
   myKitten->changeColor(color)
}
```

To make things clear, my question is : 
Is it possible to return my native kitten to java code ? how ? is it the right approach.

Comment: Presumably you want to pass a *kitten\**, not a *kitten*.

Comment: thanks, fixed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic problem is *how to pass a pointer from C++ to Java and receive it back*, there is nothing special in `this` pointer. One of the best articles is an [old post](https://rkennke.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/efficient-jni-programming-iv-wrapping-native-data-objects/) by Roman Kennke, but [the short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634310/192373) can be found on SO:

> you can use Java **long** to get and set pointers, unless in your natie architecture pointers are more than 64 bit.