# JNI and constructors

Tags: java, c++, constructor, java-native-interface

I have a compiled library that I need to use in a project. To keep it short, it's a library for interacting with a specific piece of hardware. What I have is .a and .dll library files, for linux and windows respectively, and a bunch of C++ .h headers with all the public functions and classes described there.

The problem is that the project needs to be in Java, so I need to write a JNI wrapper for this library, and honestly, I've never done that. But that's ok, I'm down to learn the thing.

I've read up a bunch of documentation online, and I figured out passing variables, creating java objects from native code, etc.

What I can't figure out, is how to work with native constructors using JNI? I have no idea what the source code of these constructors are, I only have the headers like this:

```
namespace RFDevice {

class RFDEVICE_API RFEthernetDetector
{
public:
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  FUNCTION  RFEthernetDetector::RFEthernetDetector
    /// \brief    Default constructor of RFEthernetDetector object.
    ///           
    /// \return   void : N/A
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RFEthernetDetector();
    RFEthernetDetector(const WORD wCustomPortNumber);
```

So basically if I was to write my program in C++ (which I can't), I would do something like

```
RFEthernetDetector ethernetDetector = new RFEthernerDetector(somePort);
```

and then work with that object. But... How do I do this in Java using JNI?
I don't understand how am I supposed to create a native method for constructor, that would call the constructor from my .a library, and then have some way of working with that specific object? I know how to create java objects from native code - but the thing is I don't have any information about internal structure of the RFEthernetDetector class - only some of it's public fields and public methods.

And I can't seem to find the right articles on the net to help me out. How do I do that?

Update: A bit further clarification.

I create a .java wrapper class like this:

```
public class RFEthernetDetector
{
    public RFEthernetDetector(int portNumber)
    {
        Init(portNumber);
    }

    public native void Init(int portNumber);            // Void? Or what?
}
```

then I compile it with -h parameter to generate JNI .h file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class RFEthernetDetector */

#ifndef _Included_RFEthernetDetector
#define _Included_RFEthernetDetector
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     RFEthernetDetector
 * Method:    Init
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_RFEthernetDetector_Init
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I then create an implementation that will call the functions from my .a library:

```
#include "RFEthernetDetector.h"     // auto-generated JNI header
#include "RFEthernetDetector_native.h"  // h file that comes with the library, 
                    //contains definition of RFEthernetDetector class
/*
 * Class:     RFEthernetDetector
 * Method:    Init
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_RFEthernetDetector_Init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint value)
{
    RFEthernetDetector *rfeDetector = new RFEthernetDetector(value);    // constructor from the library
    // now how do I access this new object from Java?
    // if I need to later call rfDetector->doSomething() on that exact class instance?
}
```

Comment: JNI is a C interface: not C++.  You can write in C++ but the bits that interface with Java should be in C.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But that doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @cup Surely not? As long as you have `extern "C"`s in the right places (which you should, as `javac -h` generates them), you can use C++ all the way through, no?

Comment: Checked it, indeed you can in the JNI implementation use C++. In fact, you wouldn't be able to do things like calling class functions if you couldn't.

Comment: Does anything [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#newobject-newobjecta-newobjectv) fit your needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to build a `RFEthernetDetector` Java class that, through a pointer, *owns* a `RFEthernetDetector` on the C++ side. [This is no fun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/337268/5684257), but inter-language glue never is.

```java
// In this design, the C++ object needs to be explicitly destroyed by calling
// close() on the Java side.
// I think that Eclipse, at least, is configured by default to complain
// if an AutoCloseable is never close()d.
public class RFEthernetDetector implements AutoCloseable {
   private final long cxxThis; // using the "store pointers as longs" convention
   private boolean closed = false;
   public RFEthernetDetector(int port) {
       cxxThis = cxxConstruct(port);
   };
   @Override
   public void close() {
       if(!closed) {
           cxxDestroy(cxxThis);
           closed = true;
       }
   }
   private static native long cxxConstruct(int port);
   private static native void cxxDestroy(long cxxThis);

   // Works fine as a safety net, I suppose...
   @Override
   @Deprecated
   protected void finalize() {
       close();
   }
}
```

And on the C++ side:

```cpp
#include "RFEthernetDetector.h"

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_RFEthernetDetector_cxxConstruct(JNIEnv *, jclass, jint port) {
    return reinterpret_cast<jlong>(new RFEthernetDetector(port));
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_RFEthernetDetector_cxxDestroy(JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong thiz) {
    delete reinterpret_cast<RFEthernetDetector*>(thiz);
    // calling other methods is similar:
    // pass the cxxThis to C++, cast it, and do something through it
}
```

If all that `reinterpret_cast`ing makes you feel uncomfortable, you could choose to instead keep a `map` around:

```cpp
#include <map>

std::map<jlong, RFEthernetDetector> references;

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_RFEthernetDetector_cxxConstruct(JNIEnv *, jclass, jint port) {
    jlong next = 0;
    auto it = references.begin();
    for(; it != references.end() && it->first == next; it++) next++;
    references.emplace_hint(it, next, port);
    return next;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_RFEthernetDetector_cxxDestroy(JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong thiz) {
    references.erase(thiz);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I did in my own solution that I've posted half an hour ago. Is there no other method than basically passing a "long" address every time you want to access an instance of an object? I mean, it works, but it doesn't look like fun, as you put it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build the `native` class in Java, then run the `javah` program which will build the stubs that Java expects.  You'll then need to map the java stubs to the C++ code to compile and distribute that binding library along with your java program.

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Comment: I know all of that. You misunderstand the question. As I said, I figured out how to pass arguments, call native functions from a library, etc. My problem is specifically with CONSTRUCTORS. As in, the native library has a constructor for a class that does something, and creates and inits the class in native code. And then I need to somehow call functions ON THAT NATIVE CLASS INSTANCE, but I obviously can't access it directly from the JVM. How do I make a constructor that creates instance of a C++ class and then work with that instance of C++ (not java) class from java?

Comment: Ah, I see your question.  I'm not sure the constructor itself can be hooked by JNI.  You might need a private static call that you make from within the constructor to create the context.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I ended up doing for now is basically storing the address in my .java class as "long" variable, and then have Init() method return the address of C++ instance as jlong.

Then, when I need to call something on that instance of a class - I pass the address as an additional argument and do the transformation in the C code like this (tested on test class / custom .so):

```
//constructor wrapper
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_Test_Greetings(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jint value)
{
    Greetings *greetings = new Greetings(value);
    return (jlong)greetings;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_HelloWorld(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jlong reference)
{
    Greetings *greetings;
    greetings = (Greetings*)reference;
    greetings->helloValue();
}
```

I have no idea if that's the correct way to do it, but it works... would appreciate if someone tells me how wrong I am.