# How to use instances of c++ classes in java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have some c++ class:

```cpp
class Test{
  public:
    int a,b,c;
    Test(){
        a=b=c=3;
    }
};
```

How to use it in jvm?
Like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.loadLibrary("Test")
    Test t=new Test();
    System.out.println(t.a+" "+t.b+" "+t.c);
}
```

In all examples that I found methods been are static-like, non dependent on instance

Comment: Have you looked at JNI? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Comment: Yes, but "In all examples that I found methods been are static-like, non dependent on instance"

Comment: @hohserg https://stackoverflow.com/a/58178767/3199595

Comment: For a quick start, look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html)